# How do put a bullet list in docstring for 'Raises'?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, bulletedlist

I couldn't figure out how to create a bullet list for `Raises`. See below. Is it even possible? What I got is a single bullet point for `RuntimeError` (same for `ValueError`).
Like:

```
   Raises:      • RuntimeError -
                     ◦ case1: when x happens * case 2: when y happens
                • ValueError -
                     ◦ a is not all lowercase * current day is Sunday
```

```
class A
    def f1(self, a: str):
        """f1

        Parameters
        ----------
        a: str
            a

        Raises
        ------
        RuntimeError
            * case 1: when x happens
            * case 2: when y happens

        ValueError
            * ``a`` is not all lowercase
            * current day is Sunday
        """
```

Comment: I don't think the NumPy (or Google) style supports bullet lists in docstring sections such as `Raises`. You can have a single paragraph of plain text. See https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#raises.

Comment: Additional information. Visual Studio Code render the above as what I want (when I mouse over the function)